# Is it possible to restrict forwarding in HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, jplayer

I am trying to restrict forwarding in my HTML5 video element. But is there any possibility to do this.

I want to restrict the fast forwarding of the video, However backward navigation should be allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by forwarding?

Comment: @lan Devlin..I want to restrict the forward navigation of the video, However backward navigation should be allowed.

Comment: @IanDevlin: fast forward

Comment: @lanDevlin... Yes fast forward...

Comment: Can you include the HTML you are using to show the video ...

Comment: I guessed that's what he meant I just wanted to be sure...

Comment: @IanDevlin: It didn't make sense for me either since forward/backward sounds like browser navigation. Is comment about restriction helped me :)

Answer (score 5):

Well it's not perfect but you could always save the current timestamp everytime and compare with that. If it goes after the current timestamp, just reset it back to the old one.

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
var previousTime = 0;
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event) {
    previousTime = video.currentTime;
});

video.addEventListener("seeking", function(event) {
    if (video.currentTime > previousTime)
        video.currentTime = previousTime;
});
```

I tried to find a way to cancel the seeking events for a smoother result but couldn't get it to work. If anyone has any insight on how to cancel those, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include a `controls` attribute and then implement your own UI. You can create a fast forward button that does whatever you like … or not include one at all.